# How to debug PHP mail?

Tags: php

A simple script, simple mail function I called in my localhost and live server.

```
$message = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";

$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

$rs = mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'My Subject', $message);
```

Both of them return bool true. 
With the localhost, I can receive email but in the live server, I cannot receive any mail.

Then I check `/var/mail/www-data` there is a message:

```
Mailing to remote domains not supported
```

Linux, Apache, or PHP problem?

Comment: Have you setup a mailserver on your serversystem? If you have, have you enabled remote domain mailing?

Comment: it is debian. just check and there is exim. i will try to figure out the configuration. thanks man

Comment: For sure. Mailservers are a big pice of work to make function and work correctly. I hope you will figure it out.

Comment: Try [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), it helped me a lot with managing mail functions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a smtp server configuration issue, but since you are asking how to debug PHP mail, the best approach would be sniffing the tcp conversation. To do that you can capture the conversation using *wireshark* (or *tcpdump* if you are on console) and inspect the actual commands sent to and from the server.

Comment: cool, i will try out wireshark. seem something really interesting :)